# Get data from same row with MAX()?

Tags: sql, mariadb, groupwise-maximum, mariadb-10.4

[MariaDB 10.4, PHP8.0]
How can I rewrite this so it works so it **get weight_date from the row with MAX(total_weight) and list it AS highest_weight_date**? I have read that we can't use MAX() among with WHERE?
I have tested to rewrite several examples, but I give up and embarrassed show my latest try:

```
weight_date HAVING total_weight=MAX(total_weight) AS highest_weight_date
```

I try to add it to this but I get error.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9c057570bd60cdf20a7148189a77fdc4

```
    SELECT *
           , LEAD(total_weight, 1) OVER(
               ORDER BY weight_date DESC
           ) AS prev_total_weight
           , LEAD(weight_date, 1) OVER(
               ORDER BY weight_date DESC
           ) AS prev_total_weight_date
    
           , MIN(total_weight) OVER() AS lowest_weight
           , MAX(total_weight) OVER() AS highest_weight
 
           , FROM_UNIXTIME(weight_date, '%u') AS weight_week
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
              ORDER BY weight_date DESC
           ) AS RowNum      

    FROM   (
              SELECT *, weight_start_week + weight_end_week AS total_weight
              FROM   YourTable
           ) t
    ORDER BY RowNum
```

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh MariaDB 10.4, PHP8.0

Comment: This class of problem is known as [tag:groupwise-maximum].

Comment: `weight_start_week + weight_end_week AS total_weight` doesn't make sense to me, unless weight_start_week is an absolute number and weight_end_week is a delta?

Comment: oh, maybe you are trying to get the average weight for the week and don't care that it is doubled?

Comment: @ysth I'm collecting data in the beginning(weekend) and end (weekdays) of every week. In one place of my webpage I want to show a short list of the total.  1. Latest total, date, change compare to previous.... 2. Record low, date of record low.  3. Record high, date of record high....  But I also have charts which requires me having separate values from each part of the week... My query result in same MAX/MIN value on each row, and I want the same for the date.

Comment: still doesn't make sense to me; what *are* weight_start_week and weight_end_week and why are you adding them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the highest_weight_date (the weight_date from the row that has the highest total_weight), you just want to add to your select:

```
FIRST_VALUE(weight_date) OVER (ORDER BY total_weight DESC) AS highest_weight_date
```

though I would recommend doing `ORDER BY total_weight DESC, weight_date` or `ORDER BY total_weight DESC, weight_date DESC` so you deterministically get either the first or last date with that weight, not an arbitrary one, when the weight occurs on more than one date.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dd7faeb7159d7c5f9084c2d79584eb6d)

Answer (score 0):

> I have read that we can't use MAX() among with WHERE?

Maybe this helps: use a subquery to find the MAX() weight in the WHERE clause.  Using your sample data ...

```
select from_unixtime( weight_date )
from YourTable
where ( weight_start_week + weight_end_week ) = ( 
  select max( weight_start_week + weight_end_week ) 
  from YourTable 
) ;

-- result
from_unixtime( weight_date )
2022-01-14 00:00:00
```

[DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1a751e73d9c1a9ec1564acc4b39447d0)